# My NGINX configuration is now throwing 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu) EE. 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, nginx, php-7, enterprise-1.14

I'm going to try and make this as detailed as possible because I feel like I've tried everything and at this point just need another set of eyes on everything.

I'm running a **cloud server** and I've installed my **LAMP stack via terminal**. Additionally, this is a magento build. I've migrated all files to the proper folder. var/www/html and I've installed mysql and imported my DB.

I'm currently able to run mywebsite.com/info.php

```
tki@me:/$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
tki@me:/$ ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 18:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  6 18:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Feb  4 15:48 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
tki@me:/$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
sendmail-  1084               root    3u  IPv4  14208      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
sendmail-  1084               root    5u  IPv4  14209      0t0  TCP localhost:587 (LISTEN)
sshd       1122               root    3u  IPv4  14322      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1122               root    4u  IPv6  14331      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
mysqld    14732              mysql   19u  IPv4  76527      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Here is my sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #server_name server_domain_or_IP;
     server_name mysite.com;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    # fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Is there anything blatantly obvious that's wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

If that Nginx configuration is for Magento 2 (you didn't specify which version of Magento is) then you should include into your:

```
 sites-enabled/default.conf
```

this configuration:

[nginx config for magento2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/nginx.conf.sample)

the best approach is to create an additional file and include it into your server defaul.

---

**Update Answer**

Crossed myself this problem couple days ago.

It was happening because these variables were receiving the following values from Nginx:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = 'default';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = 'store';
```

while my default customer store was `english`.

After carefully checking the configuration and passing the right values from Nginx:

```
set $MAGE_RUN_CODE english;
set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
```

I went into the PHP-FPM configuration file, the one where the fastcgi params are passed further and had the surprise to find the values 
 wrong hardcoded:

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE 'defaul'
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE 'store';
```

In fact it should have been these:

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
```

Which allows you to pass the upper defined value from Nginx to Magento.

So in your case I would have a look in this file:

> include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

you have it in your nginx conf.

Comment: It's not for magento 2, sorry that i didn't specify. I'll add that now.